# Flutter, How to use firebase query .orderBy() on timestamp data?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore

I have stored time stamp data in firebase, I am fetching it using streams and displaying it in the latest date order in a datatable widget. I used `.orderBy` to access `descending` bool. But neither true nor false worked, instead `!snapshot.hasData` condition is getting executed, Why orderBy is not working and what are the other queries that I can use to get the latest date order.

```
stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
                        .collection('lender')
                        .doc(auth.currentUser!.email)
                        .collection('paymentData')
                        .where('name',
                            isEqualTo: Provider.of<UpdateNameProvider>(context,
                                    listen: false)
                                .bname).orderBy('paidDate', descending: true)
                        .snapshots(),

                    //.snapshots(),

                    builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
                      if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                        return const Center(
                            child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                          backgroundColor: Color(0xff8eacbb),
                        ));
                      }
```

Comment: Did you already check if the `snapshot` has any error?

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible reasons why a snapshot doesn't have data. At the very least you'll want to check if there's an error, and if so: log it somewhere.

Something like this:

```
builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
  if (snapshot.hasError) { // 
    return Text(snapshot.error); // 
  }
  ...
```

Comment: Checking for error worked, So, I had to create the index in firebase to get query.

Comment: Good to hear, and that is a common mistake indeed. Keep in mind: never ignore potential errors, as nowadays many SDKs give very actionable error messages.

Comment: an approach for newbies who need to build the firebase index: i couldn't get the index in firebase correct, so i deleted indexes in firebase, ran the code, and then vs code gave me the exact url to build the firebase index correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this.

```
  FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('lender')
      .doc(auth.currentUser!.email)
      .collection('paymentData')
      .orderBy('paidDate', descending: true).where('name',
  isEqualTo: Provider.of<UpdateNameProvider>(context,
  listen: false)
      .bname)
      .snapshots(),
```

Comment: I've tried that already but didn't work